# MongoDB Reverse t, i in timestamp field

Tags: mongodb, unix-timestamp, mongodb-compass

I have a csv file [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz9d9.png) to import to a mongodb database using mongodbcompass. One of the fields in the file is a timestamp (unix epochs). When importing I mark it as timestamp but the result is the timestamp going under "i" and not under "t" like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT3De.png). Is there a way to reverse this ?

Expectation was the exact opposite, the timestamp to go under "t", at least this is what i see in all online examples

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

The Timestamp type is 64 bit value where the high 32 bits are the epoch time (t), and the low 32 bits are the index/counter(i).  If you want to import an epoch time as a Timestamp, you will need to shift it 32 bits to the left, or multiply by 2^32.

You may have better luck with the UTD datetime type, which is a 64 bit integer containing the number of milliseconds since the start of the epoch.  To convert the epoch time, multiply by 1000, or append "000" to the end of each.